# Does f2py perform differently with the different versions of Fortran and CPython

Tags: python, fortran, word-wrap, f2py

There are several version of Fortran (66, 77, 90, 95, 2003, 2008) and there are two versions of CPython (2.x and 3.x).

From user experience I would like to know whether f2py is faster, more memory efficient or robust when writing the Fortran source code in a specific version.

Secondly, does f2py support Python 3.x and if so does it perform better for 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: The version of Fortran *standard* does not matter in speed at all (let's forget automatic reallocation checks for now). What matters is the *compiler* and its *version*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, and the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/c-info.python-as-glue.html#f2py) it is **not** `f2py` that makes the difference - it is your or the final users **Fortran** compiler - `f2py` generates a wrapper not compiles the code itself.  For those Fortran dialects that are not mentioned i.e. 90, 2003 & 2008 as specifically supported you *may*, (depending on the features that your code uses), have to generate the interfaces yourself.

I have not tried `f2py` under python 3 but the current `numpy` [notes](http://www.scipy.org/install.html#python3) suggest that *most* packages are available.  Again it will be the **Fortran** compiler that will determine the speed and memory footprint of the extension.